# ggplot() error while using it in a function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I need a help on ggplot() which I am using for the very first time.
I have a function defined as follows :

```
myHist <- function(data, varName = "") {
gp <- ggplot(data, aes(data[, varName]))
gp <- gp + geom_histogram(alpha = 1, aes(fill=..count..))
gp <- gp + labs(title = paste("Histogram for ", varName, sep = " "))
gp <- gp + labs(x = varName, y = "N") 
gp <- gp + scale_fill_gradient("", low = "blue", high = "red")
gp
```

}

then using it as follows :

```
myHist(data = iris, varName = "Petal.Width")
```

which gives the following error :

```
"Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'varName' not found"
```

can anyone help ? while debugging if I initialize the parameters passed the inner part of the function works. But the function itself doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `aes_string` because your variable is an input value of the function stored as a character value.

```
myHist <- function(data, varName = "") {
  gp <- ggplot(data=data, aes_string(varName))
  gp <- gp + geom_histogram(alpha = 1, aes(fill=..count..))
  gp <- gp + labs(title = paste("Histogram for", varName, sep = " "))
  gp <- gp + labs(x = varName, y = "N") 
  gp <- gp + scale_fill_gradient("", low = "blue", high = "red")
  gp}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked...@Agenis

Comment: @agnenis: I am new to this site, I clicked on the tick mark on the left of the post, is that what u wanted me to do ? & yes it does solve my problem